# Semantics of dependencies

Tags: semantics

Is it correct to say that if **task a** depends on **task b**, **task a** is the *dependent task* and **task b** is the *depending task*?

Comment: A look at the etymology may help. _Dependent, independent, dependence,_ and _depending_ all come from the Latin verb _pendeo_, meaning 'to hang from; to weigh'. Anything that is pendulous is hanging low, like a pendulum. If one task depends on or is depending from another, it's lower; consequently _dependent_ and _depending_ can't be used as opposites. In your question, just as in math, if ***a*** depends on ***b***, then ***a*** is the dependent variable, and ***b*** is the independent variable (or task, if you prefer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Task A is both the *dependent task* and the *depending task.*

From [Oxford Dictionaries Online:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dependent)

> (**dependent on/upon**) Contingent on or determined by:
>
> ‘the various benefits will be dependent on length of service’

So anything that is depending will be dependent.